# How could I tell Google Search that there are another 3 similar products on a Product web page with JSON-LD?

Tags: seo, json-ld

Our team are using JSON-LD to describe page content. Main SEO target is Google Search Engine.

I have a primary `Product` on the web page for selling. At same time, I would like to display 3 similar `Product`s for user's reference at the bottom of page.

I know I can describe my primary Product with below basic script:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Semantic Web Primer (First Edition)",
    "offers":
     {
         "@type": "Offer",
         "price": "2.95",
         "priceCurrency": "USD"
     },
 }
</script>
```

But how could I add information of rest 3 similar `Product` into above script? How to tell Google that those 3 `Product` is similar to current primary `Product` on the web page?

I searched https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#data-model and https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11/#reverse-properties, tried to find out solution but with no lucky.

Could someone help me on this? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could try isSimiarTo https://schema.org/isSimilarTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON-LD is just the syntax. The semantics come from a vocabulary (or multiple vocabularies), which defines the properties and types you can make use of in JSON-LD.

You are using the `Product` type from the vocabulary Schema.org. All expected properties are listed on its page: https://schema.org/Product

As you are looking for a property that expects a `Product` as value, you can check all properties that list "Product" in the column "Expected Type" of the first table:

- [`isAccessoryOrSparePartFor`](https://schema.org/isAccessoryOrSparePartFor)
- [`isConsumableFor`](https://schema.org/isConsumableFor)
- [`isRelatedTo`](https://schema.org/isRelatedTo)
- [`isSimilarTo`](https://schema.org/isSimilarTo)
- [`material`](https://schema.org/material)

(In addition, you could also check for properties that list "Thing" as expected value, as every `Product` is also a `Thing`.)

In your case, it seems that [`isSimilarTo`](https://schema.org/isSimilarTo) is suitable:

> A pointer to another, functionally similar product (or multiple products).

(If no property were suitable, you can’t express this relation in Schema.org. You could then make use of a property from another vocabulary, or create your own.)

---

If your goal is getting the product rich result in Google Search, note that these properties don’t seem to be relevant for this rich result. All relevant properties are listed in their documentation: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product#product